# Does NSKeyedUnarchiver autorelease?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nskeyedarchiver

I'm doing some archiving to a property list and when I unarchive my data using NSKeyedUnarchiver I find that my app crashes if I release the object afterward. I was wondering if the finishDecoding message also autoreleases the object. Seems weird that it crashes when I release it.

Comment: If the method name doesn't have copy in it and you don't message the object with alloc, new or retain, then you should not release it. So objects you unarchive with the convenience methods on NSKeyedUnarchiver must be retained or copied if you want to own them and you should not release them /unless/ you do retain or copy them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you release? NSKeyedUnarchiver or unarchived object?

Should you release NSKeyedUnarchiver or not depends on how you created it. It follows usual rules. If you use `alloc` + `initForReadingWithData` you should release, if you use `unarchiveObjectWithData` or `unarchiveObjectWithFile` - you shouldn't.

Regarding result of `decodeObjectForKey`, it also follows usual rule that method returns autoreleased object and you shouldn't release it unless you explicitly retained it.

Regarding `finishDecoding`: you are expected to explicitly call it before NSKeyedUnarchiver object is released. You shouldn't use unarchiver after that point, but object is still alive.

Answer (score 0):

If you initialize the unarchiver with

```
[[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:data]
```

Then you are responsible for releasing it when yo are done unarchiving.

If it's crashing after you release it, then it's likely your bug is elsewhere.  Probably because you are using objects that your unarchiver provides without retaining them.  And when the unarchiver is deallocated, it releases the objects that provided for you.  If you didn't retain these, they will be deallocated and you will crash when you reference these objects.